# Light Behaves Weirdly Only on One Mesh

Tags: mesh, lighting, shadows

So here's the problem: I'm trying to get a starship to behave properly to light, but it only seems to respond at certain angles. The best way I can describe it is that there's specific angles that when the camera faces them they're dark, the area seems to move with the camera, like as I rotate it around the ship at a certain point darkness suddenly just encroaches the ship.[image: This might be the darkest point]

[image: The point where the shadows start enveloping the ship]

[image: What the opposite side looks like]

It behaves like this with or without lights in a scene so I think the problem is with the Mesh but I already checked the normals and they're facing the right way, I've been trying to figure out what may be causing this but to no avail. And just to reiterate the shadows seem to move with the camera, (not the camera object but my viewing angle) but don't follow it completely around the ship, they're just at their strongest at a specific angle, but I think weaker shadows follow it around but I can't be certain.

[image: This is my main material]
[image: This is the Glass material for the window]

[image]

Comment: What does the shader/material look like? Does the object have custom normals?

Comment: There's a bunch of them on this object I can post an image of two of them and let you see if there's anything wrong with it, but no I haven't touched the normals at all. (I did mess with them to try and fix the problem but I undid all of that.

Comment: Not a diagnosis, but it's very odd to plug  a _Displacement_  vector output in to the 'Normal' input of  a _Bump_ node. Typically _Bump_ would expect a scalar 'Height', and optionally, a vector 'Normal', which for some reason is not the default. Typically, the output of a _Displacement_ would be into the 'Displacement' input of a _Material_ output node. Can you share a little sample, say, of a chunk with one of the materials, on https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: I can definitely do that if you can explain how I could share a chunk at all.

Comment: You've tried deleting all lights in the scene? Are you using an HDRI background? Try disconnecting your Bump node from the shader.

Comment: I just thought, if the model is huge, or copyright, or whatever, edit a piece out of it with a failing material, and share a blend with the piece in it, and packed images, if relevant.

Comment: Yes I have, but the darkness still persisted.  I am not using a background, I actually just have a plane in the back with a picture on it, I moved that plane from one image to the next to show it isn't affecting the lighting. Also I did disconnect the bump map however I really need this texture to work so I can't exactly get rid of it.

Comment: Also the ship is completely original, However I can definitely get a chunk out and post it.

Comment: Ok I Think I uploaded the chunk.

Comment: Xenoture .. Blend-exchange should have given you a link to share it with.. you can edit the link into your Q.

Comment: You are correct I just thought it directly uploaded it to this post, that was my mistake.

Comment: I do want to say I've done a lot of repurposing and I only have some basic knowledge of nodes so I end up reusing old nodes from old works and copying them into new things, deleting what's irrelevant an replacing them with what I want. I have a poor memory of what everything does but that node configuration is how I do bump maps. However the results are like a chimera of instructions from various tutorials because typically it takes a few to get the results I want.

Comment: OK, images not packed, so can't be definitive. But recommend simplifying. Separate  (blend file) for modelling and materials only, With only model / lighting / materials.  No simulations, animation.. And then build up materials simply, step by step. From the image names, i'm guessing they should be connected directly to the Principled BSDF.. like [this](https://imgur.com/cfuZ7Ab). (The weird shading seems to originate with the connection of _Displacement_ to _Bump_). Normals seem OK.

Comment: See that does get rid of the effect that's messing with the lighting but it also gets rid of the texture I want. I absolutely hate how it looks when I apply the image into the color, I actually am trying to keep the original colors of the images I have as far from this as possible. However you are correct. You've pointed me in the right direction, after you told me that I started fiddling with the displacement node and cranked the height up to 16.1 (I have no clue what this thing does only that it's nessicary for some reason) and after setting it up like that now the shadow effect is gone.

Comment: So apparently changing the height setting on my displacement node to 16.1 solved the problem. I have no clue how or why but I can't argue with results.